# How to delete decimals from the price with number_format

Tags: php, html, numbers, format

I would like to know if anyone can tell me how I delete the decimals from the price of the ads on my site.

I have a free classifieds website, but I can not understand how to delete decimals. I do not need them

For example:

If the price of an object is 100 $
Currently it is shown as 100.00 $

I'm interested in eliminating the last few decimals, so you always have the $ 100 price

I think it's the number_format to change or I do not know, I've tried various changes.

Generally how do you change?

My site is visible here annuncigratuiti.com

Comment: Hi maybe the [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function can help you.

Comment: In But on which php page should I enter the code according to your opinion? For example, if you look at this [link](https://www.annuncigratuiti.com/moto-e-scooter/piaggio-x10-350-executive-marrone-2013/napoli-43.html), this is where I want the price without decimals, but I can not figure out which page to change the code

Comment: Is this website based on some CMS platforms like, Woocommerce ? Magento ? Opencart ? etc ?

Comment: No, is native php without cms

Comment: @antoniomaraucci We could not figure out the code based on the web page result, be aware that an ECommerce is far from being an easy stuff and you should not venture yourself in developing one if you just started learning PHP.

Comment: I did not create the code, but an expert in Germany, I am Italian and I know the basics of php, html, css and java, I managed to do many things and many adjustments and additions, but I just can not it. The only thing that told me the programmer who created my site and I have to use number_format and then I should understand how to do this [link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php) but i no understand how :(

Comment: Not even from the examples that show how it works at the same link?

Comment: @paul-t Here you can see website same [link](https://www.subito.it/auto/bmw-118-d-eletta-122-cv-km-72000-torino-272156433.htm) and him use price without decimals.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = number_format($var, 0, '.', ''); 

echo $var;
```

but it return as string, to make it as float :

```
$var = (float)number_format($var, 0, '.', '');
```

Comment: Where i enter this code in your opinion? you see my website? [link](https://www.annuncigratuiti.com)